# Rails Mobile API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have an existing Rails project which uses Omniauth-facebook gem to connect to gem. Only facebook users can interact and use the website. I am now developing a mobile application, and want to build an API for the current Rails project.

Which gem should I use to build an API?
Should I use two different Rails projects, one for website and one for API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails is already API ready, here is a quick example

lets imagine you want to show all the products of your app in a mobile app

lets go to the products controller:

Controller:

```
  def index
    @products = Product.all       

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end
```

as you can see you can render the json within the controller, then in your mobile app you can do a request on that with the json extension something like this:

```
$.post('www.example.com/products.json', function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

now you adapt your mobile app to read that json, and thats basicly how it works

Comment: But how should I handle sessions?

Comment: usualy api requests dont handle sessions, the send the login info always within each request

Comment: But as I said I'm using Facebook Authentication, so actually there is nothing to verify, because Facebook API doesn't allow you to use/verify user password

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) one called rails-api.

A cool screencast is here:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem